# AOT - Lazy loaded routes are not being compiled

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, aot

Does anyone know why when I `ngc` my project, the lazy loaded modules used in the project are not being compiled/generated?
This is the lazy loaded route:

```js
children: [
    …
    {
        path: "my-apps",
        loadChildren: "carbonldp-panel/my-apps/my-apps.module#MyAppsModule",
    },
]
```

This is the output, no `my-apps.module.ngfactory.ts` file is being generated:

[image]

The ***ONLY*** way to generate it, is by imporing it in the routing file, but that’s not lazy loading:

```js
import { MyAppsModule } from "carbonldp-panel/my-apps/my-apps.module”;
```

Comment: So it pushed everything in _node_modules_?

Comment: The thing is that `carbonldp-panel` is a library of a main project.
I am compiling the main project which has more dependencies ( carbonldp-panel, carbonldp, angular2-carbonldp), and it generates the ngfactory files for the angular project (angular2-carbonldp and carbonldp-panel).
The main project uses some modules provided by `carbonldp-panel` and it compiles them ONLY when they are imported, but not when they are lazy loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Rollup requires a single entry point and relies on `import` and `export` statements for tree-shaking.

Lazy loading presents a problem because it can't be traced through `import/export` statements alone.

It's not ideal, but I suggest creating a separate entry file for the purposes of the build that includes the main app and all the lazy loaded modules:

**entry.ts**

```
import './main.ts';
import { MyAppsModule } from "carbonldp-panel/my-apps/my-apps.module";
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
export default {
  entry: 'entry.js',
  ...
};
```

**[Edit]**

I noticed that you deployed a module to the `node_modules` folder and you're now trying to re-use that module in your application in an AOT build.
If its not generating the necessary factory file for your module, I would check the `carbondIdp-panel` module to ensure that the `.metadata` files for your lazy loaded module was generated as part of the build.  NGC needs the metadata file to generate the factories.

I hope this helps!